# socket failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, socket

Estava criando um projeto em Android que o faça se comunicar com uma máquina Windows através de Sockets, sendo a máquina o servidor, e o dispositivo móvel (Samsung Galaxy S3 MINI) o cliente.

Criei uma rede hospedada de wireless no computador, e conectei o dispositivo no pc via cabo USB, porém me conectei a rede wireless que criei no  computador.

Fiz que quando houvesse um erro, o erro seja escrito em um TextView, e retornou o erro:

```
socket failed: EACCES (Permission Denied)
```

Código Activity:
http://pastebin.com/rw9rzE9P

ManiFest.xml
http://pastebin.com/bxaDaubx

Answer (score 2):

Há alguns detalhes no seu código.

No manifesto, a linha

```
<permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Deveria ser

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Com relação ao código da `Activity`, ao criar uma instância da classe `Socket`, você está criando uma conexão TCP/IP com um destino qualquer, que no caso do seu código é o próprio celular:

```
socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",5000);
```

O IP `127.0.0.1`, referencia a própria máquina/dispositivo (é o IP de [loopback](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback)), ou seja, você não estaria se conectando ao computador dessa forma. Você deveria substituir esse IP pelo IP do seu computador.

Além disso, você deve garantir que exista algum programa/serviço no computador, "escutando" na porta 5000, caso contrário, a conexão também falhará.

Comment: Esse 127.0.0.1 foi uma forma de 'esconder' meu IP, eu digitei ipconfig para pegar o IP da conexão que estou compartilhando com o celular, estou conectado a um Wifi que disponibiliza a internet, e o outro eu compartilho a internet, no caso o que eu conecto com o dispositivo na máquina com a rede "Wireless Network Connection 2", devo pegar o IP dessa rede que compartilho com o dispositivo?

Comment: OK! Mas, em um exemplo, eu colocaria algo como `"X.X.X.X"`, ou até mesmo `"..."` ;) Sim, você deve utilizar o IP da rede onde o celular está. Agora, existe um serviço rodando na máquina, escutando na porta 5000 desse IP?